# Provide rownumbers while conditionally restart counting

Tags: r

Say, I have a dataframe

```
s<-c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5))
TF<-c('T','F','F','T','T','F','F','F','F','T')
df<-data.frame(s,TF)
df
```

I would like to know the rownumbers of all T's, but I want to restart counting the rownumbers for each unique s number. So, for this example I would like to get:

```
s    rn1   rn2
1    1     4
2    5     10
```

In reality I have thousands of cases, so it would be extremely helpful if I can get some kind of nifty code to do it for me. Any help is very much appreciated.
In my attempt, I could not figure out how to restart counting the rows:

```
tapply(1:nrow(df), df$s, function(x)  x[which(df$TF[x])])
```

Comment: I don't understand how you got your desired output from your input. It looks like `s=1` has three T's at 1, 4, and 5. And what do you mean by "restarting" the row numbers? You seem to continue counting from 1. How exactly do you want the results returned?

Comment: I suspect there’s an error in your example: the output row numbers would be 1, 4, 5 for s=1, and 10 for s=2. This exemplifies why your desired output format can’t work: the number of columns differ.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution:

```
> lapply(split(df, df$s), function(x) rownames(x)[x$TF == 'T'])
$`1`
[1] "1" "4" "5"

$`2`
[1] "10"
```

Answer (score 1):

The following solution using dplyr does what you want, but it preserves the tidy data format rather than spreading the values across columns. This is necessary, since the number of columns would differ for s=1 and s=2 — an impossibility.

```
df %>%
    mutate(nr = row_number()) %>%
    filter(TF) %>%
    select(-TF)
```

The output is:

```
      s    nr
1     1     1
2     1     4
3     1     5
4     2    10
```